# How to time the for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, time, break

I am having a code where I have a **for loop**

I want that for loop run some specific time and then it stop or exit. I tried to find solutions like this:

```
import time
    **NOT HELPFUL for me**
    def stopwatch(seconds):
        start = time.time()
        time.clock()    
        elapsed = 0
        while elapsed < seconds:
            elapsed = time.time() - start 
            time.sleep(1)  

    stopwatch(20)
```

My code is like this:

```
for a in list:

   if condition true:
     print('Condition True')
   else 
     print('not true')
```

So, i just need to run this loop for few seconds and then stop. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why you don't use event scheduler. https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html

Comment: Yes i saw that but no idea how to use that here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just subtract start time from current time (in seconds)

```
import time
start = time.time()
for a in list:
    if time.time()-start > maxTimeout:
        break
    print("condition true" if condition else "not true")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and sharing the easy way.